# Interface hierarchy

Tags: java, interface, class-hierarchy

I have a problem with interface hierarchy. My projects has four class and six interface in a rigid structure, that is:

```
public interface Set<T, N extends Settable<T,N>>
public interface Settable<T, N>
public interface Sequence<T, N extends Sequenceable<T,N>> extends Set<T,N>
public interface Sequenceable<T,N> extends Settable<T,N>
public interface DisjoinedSet<T, N extends DisjoinedSettable<T,N>> extends Set<T,N>
public interface DisjoinedSettable<T,N> extends Settable<T,N>

public class List<T> implements Sequence<T, NodeList<T>>
public class NodeList<T> implements Sequenceable<T,NodeList<T>>
public class ListDisjoined<T> extends List<T> implements DisjoinedSet<T,NodeListDisjoined<T>>, Sequence<T,NodeListDisjoined<T>>
public class NodeListDisjoined<T> extends List<T> implements DisjoinedSettable<T,NodeListDisjoined<T>>, Sequenceable<T,NodeListDisjoined<T>>
```

Beside the horrible naming, the idea is that by creating container-contained couples of classes/interfaces I gain an enormous amount of sinergy: I can simply write the body of those methods inside the comments of the interfaces and copy&past on a whole brunch of classes, without changing anyting.

However, I got two errors on the last two class:

```
The interface Sequence cannot be implemented more than once with different arguments: Sequence<T,NodeList<T>> and Sequence<T,NodeListDisjoined<T>>
The interface Sequenceable cannot be implemented more than once with different arguments: Sequenceable<T,NodeList<T>> and Sequenceable<T,NodeListDisjoined<T>>
```

`NodeListDisjoined` is a subclass of `NodeList`, so what is the problem?

Note: the edit written under this line works. I still do not understand why.

```
public interface DisjoinedSet<T, N extends DisjoinedSettable<T,N>> extends Sequence<T,N>
public interface DisjoinedSettable<T,N> extends Sequenceable<T,N>
```

Comment: The problem is you wouldn't want to be able to add a `NodeList` to a collection of type `NodeListDisjoined`

Comment: ? The header of the class `ListDisjoined` specifies that only object of type `NodeListDisjoined` are acceptable as nodes.              The class `NodeList` is mentioned only once in the code of the classes `NodeListDisjoined` and `ListDisjoined`: when I explain that `NodeListDisjoined` extends `NodeList`.